# Converting the result of Normal@ to normal table form

Tags: list-manipulation, format

Consider a command which extracts the contour of RegionPlot:

```
x1 = RegionPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2] >= 0.1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]
Cases[Normal@x1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

The second string returns an array in the form {{1,2} {3,4}}, while I want to convert it to a table form
$$
1 \ 2
$$
$$
3 \ 4
$$ Could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Maybe you get the desired output by applying `TableForm` or `TableForm@*Transpose` to the result of `Cases`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : I want the result to be in a form of the ordinary table
$$1\ 2$$
$$3 \ 4$$
But your command gives something in the form
$$1$$
$$2$$
$$3$$
$$4$$

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : I've corrected the comment.

Comment: Are you looking for `Flatten`? Or maybe `Partition[Flatten[#],1]&`?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher : thank you! The command Partition[Flatten[#],2] helped me.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: also `Join @@ Cases[Normal@x1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]`?

Comment: What about `Cases[Normal@x1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Ulrich Neumann has given the best solution, so I'm recording it as a answer.

```
x1 = RegionPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2] >= 0.1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}];
m = Cases[Normal@x1, Line[x_] :> x, ∞][[1]];
TableForm[m]
```

[image: table]